# How to query Supabase to filter with relationship table and pagination?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I have two tables `job` and `category` with a 1:M relationship. I want to fetch up to 10 jobs at a time using pagination for a given `category_name`, which is a column from the table `category`. `category_name` value is of type JobCategoryEnum.

I have tried various ways to achieve this using `.eq()` filtering and `.range()` pagination but it fails for now:

```
async function fetchJobsByCategory(category:JobCategoryEnum, page = 1, pageSize = 10) {

    const { data, error } = await supabaseBrowserClient
            .from('job')
            .select(
                `*, 
                category(category_name)`
            )
            .eq('job_status', 'open')
            .eq('category:category_id (category_name)', category) 
            .range((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize - 1);
    }
```

I also tried changing the filtering line to the following options:

```
.eq('category(category_name)', category) 
.eq('category.category_name', category) 
.eq('category:category_name', category)
```

I believe that I have to do this filtering before the pagination otherwise if I do the filtering client-side, I will get paginated results from my query and will miss results.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I couldn't find an explicit example on the Supabase docs. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter the referenced table, you can use the `referencedTable.column` syntax as described [here](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/using-filters?example=filter-referenced-tables). To apply the `range()` to a referenced table, you can add the `referencedTable` option to `range()`.

```js
const { data, error } = await supabaseBrowserClient
  .from('job')
  .select(`*, category!inner(category_name)`)
  .eq('job_status', 'open')
  .eq('category.category_name', category)
  .range((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I was missing the referencedTable in the range.

Comment: Actually, only when I change `.select(*, category(category_name))` to `.select(*, category!inner(category_name))` is the range applied in my results @dshukertjr

Comment: @thib Yeah, that makes sense. I misread the question and thought you wanted to paginate the `categories`, but yes if you want to paginate the `job` table, you would need the `!inner` keyword. In that case, you wouldn't need the `referenceTable` in the `range()` function either. I have updated my response just in case.